# In what case would inheriting private members be useful?

Tags: c++

I can't wrap my head around why in the world would anyone want to inherit private members.

For example:

```
class Secretive {
    private: 
       int a;
    public:
       Secretive() { a = 0; }
    private: 
       int showSecret () { return a; };
};

class Curious:public Secretive 
{ ....  }
```

Can you provide me with a concrete example in which inheriting private members are useful? And how would you go about accessing those private members?

Comment: The private members are used by the parent class… the derived class can’t access them directly. You don’t really inherit private members.

Comment: @minitech, then why inherit the parent class at all?

Comment: @minitech Or does no one in the real world actually use what I have provided as an example?

Comment: It has a member that’s not private; the constructor. Yes, it’s kind of difficult to explain with that example, since `showSecret` being private is completely useless and you wouldn’t make a class that stores one `0` for private use and does nothing else.

Comment: Are you talking about private members in general or private member _functions_ only?

Comment: @rodrigo, In general. But I think I understand now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Private member functions actually are not inherited and you cannot access them in child class. (Unless you are using overloaded private virtual member functions - in this case you cannot access base class member function too, but still it's inheritance but it has other use cases).

But anyway you want them in base class as they are used by other private/protected member functions in base class (directly or in a chained way). If it's not used by any other member function - that's true that you can delete it as unused code.

Also in [this article](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm) Herb Sutter suggests and explains use of private virtual member functions.

Comment: I don't quite like the use of the term *inherited* here. The private members (data or functions) are still part of the base subobject, they don't disappear, they are just not accessible from the derived type (but they affect lookup, take space in the case of data members, affect the dispatch mechanism for virtual functions...

Comment: Yes, I also don't like it, as IMO classes are inherited, not member functions. But still, how do they affect lookup (in case of non-virtual) and what space do they take? AFAIK member function does not affect any space constraints for data members, it can only affect size of the resulting objects if they are virtual. And about virtual member function I told explicitly in my answer

Answer (score 1):

You could certianly have a base-class with private functions that are used indirectly by a derived class:

```
class Base
{
    private:
       int x;
    public:
       Base() : x(0) {}
       int func() { pfunc(); return x; }
    private:
       void pfunc() { x++; }
};


class Derived : public Base
{
 private:
   int y;
 public:
   Derived() y(2) {}
   int dfunc()  { return y + func(); }
};


... 

Derived d;
cout << "dfunc = " << d.dfunc() << endl;
```

This would print 3.

Comment: Very nice example. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Private members are used to implement the *invariant* of a class. When you inherit from a class with an invariant, you can access the public (and protected) interface of that class, so that its invariant is held anyway. You want to inherit instead of simply adding a field, if the relation is of type *is-a* instead of *contains-a*.

For example, you have a Galaxians-type game. You have a base class `GameObject`, with private members `position`, `sprite`, the graphical resources themselves and the like; and public members `move`, `draw`...

The main ship would be a subclass of `GameObject`, but you don't modify the sprite directly, you would break all the resource management made by the base class. Instead you use the public interface, as any other class.

And you need that the main ship to be a subclass of `GameObject` so that it can be part of the game lists.

Answer (score 1):

Private member functions can contain utility or common functionality used by the public interface of the base implementation. Just because they exist does not mean they are suitable for use by derived classes.

Making member variables private allows accessor and mutator functions to restrict how they are used and what values member variables can hold. For instance if your base class maintained a pointer to an object and you wanted to prevent that member variable from being set to `nullptr`.

```
class FooBase
{
public:
    void setPointer(std::unique_ptr<int> ptr)
    {
        if(ptr.get() == nullptr)
        {
            // do something like throw an exception or set a default

        }
        else
        {
            var_ = std::move(ptr);
        }
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<int> var_;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that some to mind with this type of questions is that the language might not be as clear as it could. In particular, it is unclear what *inherited* represents to different people.

An object of type `Curious` contains a subobject of type `Secretive` and that in turn contains the member `a`. In that sense, `Curious` does contain `a` and thus it somehow *inherits* it.

The `Curious` complete object cannot directly access the `a` subobject inside the `Secretive` subobject, so some can say that it does not *have* a `a` member. It is there but not really usable from `Curious`. For those people `Curious` does not *inherit* `a`.

Why would someone declare/define things as `private` in a class to be extended then?

The answer is simple, as simple as it gets. For exactly the same reasons you make anything else `private` anywhere else. The `private` access specifier is used to mark members of the type that are implementation details and not to be used outside of this particular type, whether it is by completely unrelated or derived types does not make a difference.

The private members are there for your type needs (not for others), they are needed by `Secretive` for some functionality that it either exposes publicly to all or only to derived types through the `protected` access specifier. But those functions are not to be used by anyone else, and they might in some cases temporarily break the invariants of your type.

Consider for a somehow artificial example, an implementation of a vector that was meant to be extended in some way. It might have a pointer to the data, size and capacity that are accessible by all (included derived types), but cannot be externally modified. It could have `grow_if_need`, `move_existing_elements` or `any_other_helper` that leave the vector in an invalid state (the invariants are broken) but that when used appropriatedly (from the functions inside vector) go from one valid state of the vector to a different valid state. Those functions should not be accessed externally, as if they are they break the invariants, but they can be used to break and simplify code in your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can't a base class's private members. You can override them in C++ though, although I never saw the point in that.

So, to answer your question: no I cannot give you an example of why you would want to 'inherit' private members.

Comment: You can’t what a base class’ private members?